# Python Keras TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' % TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got 1

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

By running the test.py script which contains a keras implementation of a faster rcnn, I received this error:

```
  raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
  TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got 1
```

enriched with:

```
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File test_frcnn.py", line 125, in <module>
  shared_layers = nn.nn_base(img_input, trainable=False)
  File resnet.py", line 183, in nn_base
  x = FixedBatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name='bn_conv1')(x)

  raise TypeError("Failed to convert object of type %s to Tensor. "
  TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [1, None, 1, 1]. 
  Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

This is a very strange behaviour since it returns this error on my laptop while it perfectly runs on google colab.
What is it?
Is it possible that the compiler returns this error due to the fact that I have trained the model using colab GPU while now I'm compiling the test on my laptop using CPU?

The complete Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File test.py", line 125, in <module>
    shared_layers = nn.nn_base(img_input, trainable=False)
  resnet.py", line 183, in nn_base
    x = FixedBatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name='bn_conv1')(x)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 489, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/federicolisi/PycharmProjects/neural_networks_GIT/MakeUp_v2/keras-frcnn/keras_frcnn/FixedBatchNormalization.py", line 66, in call
    broadcast_running_mean = K.reshape(self.running_mean, broadcast_shape)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2440, in reshape
    return tf.reshape(x, shape)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 193, in reshape
    result = gen_array_ops.reshape(tensor, shape, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 8086, in reshape
    _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 473, in _apply_op_helper
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 465, in _apply_op_helper
    values = ops.convert_to_tensor(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1341, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 321, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 261, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 298, in _constant_impl
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 545, in make_tensor_proto
    raise TypeError("Failed to convert object of type %s to Tensor. "
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [1, None, 1, 1]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Comment: Could you please provide us two more things? 1) Commands you used in order to run `test.py` script, and 2) maybe full Traceback of the error and the line that is causing this problem.

Comment: Please kindly find the complete traceback on the updated topic. thank you